# JQUERY Append parent child div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi how can I append child DIV to parent div.

I saw code similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/3em3B/3/

but I need output in DIV format something like this.

```
<button id="btn-add-child">Add New Child </button>
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child1">Child 1
      <button id="btn-add-siblings">Add Siblings</button>
      <div>Sibling 1</div>
      <div>Sibling 2</div>
      <div>Sibling 3</div>
   </div>

   <div id="child2">Child 2
      <button id="btn-add-siblings">Add Siblings</button>
      <div>Sibling 1</div>
      <div>Sibling 2</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Each time I click Add new Child Button, A new child will append to the parent.

And each time I click the add siblings button, A new sibling will add according to the parent child

Comment: What do you mean "according to the parent child" ??

Comment: not clear what you are asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should give you what you want.

Adding Children and siblings dynamically.

```
var currChild = 1;

function getChildDivHtml(id) {
  return '<div id="child' + currChild + '">Child ' + currChild + '<button class="btn-add-siblings">Add Siblings</button></div>'
}


$(document).ready(function() {
$('#btn-add-child').on('click', function() {
  $('div#parent').append(getChildDivHtml(currChild));
  currChild++;
});

  $('div#parent').on('click', '.btn-add-siblings', function() {
    $(this).parent().append('<div>Sibling</div>');
  });
});
```

http://jsbin.com/xufogace/1/edit

Comment: P.S - The generated button will have a class and not an ID.

Comment: THis is what im talking about!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#btn-add-child").click(function() {

    $(parent).append($("<div>New child</div>"));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not have multiple elements with same ID. Use Class instead for button

```
<button class="btn-add-siblings">Add Siblings</button>

$('.btn-add-siblings').on('click', function() {
   $(this).parent().append('<div>Sibling</div>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.btn-add-siblings').on('click', function() {
$('#main_div').prepend('<div id="new_div">...</div>');
```

or

```
//$('#lastChildDiv').before('<div></div>');
}
```

Comment: If you paste code as an answer, please also provided an explanation as to why your answer works so that others can learn from it.